# Get the intersection from a single nested list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, data-structures, python-itertools

I have the following nested list:

```
list_ = [['The'], ['The', 'fox', 'quick'], ['quick', 'the'], ['dog']]
```

How can I compute efficiently the intersection between each sublist?:

```
['the', 'quick']
```

I tried to:

```
list(itertools.product([for e in [list_]]))
```

Comment: Do you want a list of all pairwise intersections?

Comment: @DYZ Thanks, yes!

Comment: The output doesn't make sense.  Something like `[['the'], ['quick'], []]` would make more sense.

Comment: Thanks @wim I updated.

Comment: Why is `[]`  in the result?  Why is `['the']`, since it only appears in a single sublist?

Comment: because `the` is the same that `The` @ScottHunter

Comment: @john doe No, `the` is not the same as `The`, but you can make them same by converting all your words to the lower case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, preprocess your list to make all words lower-case:

```
list_ = [set(word.lower() for word in item) for item in list_]
```

Then you want to use `itertools.combinations` and the `set()` operations:

```
results = [x&y for x,y in itertools.combinations(list_,2)]
# [{'the'}, {'the'}, set(), {'the', 'quick'}, set(), set()]
```

Comment: I noted that the output is: `[{'The'}, set(), set(), {'quick'}, set(), set()]`.  Although it is actually right, I would like to leave a single flat list: `['The' 'quick']`. I tried to remove the empty sets as follows: `list2 = [x for x in list1 if x != {}]`

Comment: Actually, `{'The'}, set(), set(), {'quick'}, set(), set()` is the correct answer.

Answer (score 3):

First, lowercase everything and create sets:

```
list_ = [['The', 'fox'], ['The', 'fox', 'quick'], ['lazy','quick', 'the', 'fox'], ['fox', 'the', 'dog']]
list2 = [{item.lower() for item in l} for l in list_]
```

Then use set operations, starting with the first set:

```
i = iter(list2)
result = next(i)
for s in i:
    result &= s
```

The result is `{'the', 'fox'}`. You can send that to the `list()` function if you want a list instead of a set. Note that using sets here will produce an arbitrary ordering.

```
>>> result
{'the', 'fox'}
>>> list(result)
['the', 'fox']
```

Answer (score 2):

Lower-case the words in your initial list:

```
l = [set(map(str.lower, sub)) for sub in list_]
```

create a unique set of all words in the lists:

```
s = set(i for sub in l for i in sub)
```

Filter them out:

```
r = [i for i in s if all(i in sub for sub in l)]
```

with `r` now containing the members that belong in all sublists.

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> list_ = [['The', 'fox'], ['The', 'fox', 'quick'], ['lazy','quick', 'the', 'fox'], ['fox', 'the', 'dog']]
```

First apply lower to all the strings:

```
>>> list_ = map(lambda l: map(lambda w: w.lower(), l), list_)
```

Second intersect the first list with the rest of the lists:

```
>>> list(set(list_[0]).intersection(*list_[1:]))
['the', 'fox']
```

Comment: I got this exception: `TypeError: 'map' object is not subscriptable`

Comment: Opps, I didn't see the python-3.x tag. This is a Python 2 answer. Toss a `list()` around each of the `map`s.

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> capital_list = list()
>>> for inner in list_:
...     capital_list.append([x.upper() for x in inner])
...
>>> capital_list
[['THE', 'FOX'], ['THE', 'FOX', 'QUICK'], ['LAZY', 'QUICK', 'THE', 'FOX'], ['FOX', 'THE', 'DOG']>>> shared = set()
>>> for inner in capital_list:
...     shared = set(inner) if not shared else shared.intersection(inner)
...
>>> shared
{'THE', 'FOX'}]
```

Convert all elements in inner lists to upper case. see the output of capital_list
find all shared elements in all shared inner lists: convert all inner lists to sets and use intersection to get shared elements